# How to redirect comment form?

Tags: 8

I want to redirect to a node after comment form submit.
But I tried  using hook_form_alter hook,the redirect not happen.

```
function pf_core_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
 if($form_id=='comment_comment_form'){
   $form['#submit'][] = 'pf_core_comment_comment_form_submit';
 }
}

function pf_core_comment_comment_form_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl('<front>');
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$nid = 1; // lets pretend the node ID you want to redirect is 1.

$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid]);
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Can you tell me how to use this code,please？I insert this code to  pf_core_comment_comment_form_submit function ,but nothing happend.

Comment: Oh.This problem was solved.I should use $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] not is $form['#submit'][].Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to redirect to a URL with parameters (rather than a fixed URL as in the example), a custom submit handler won't work because the $form object gets rebuilt, but you *can* append:

`?destination=` to `$form['#action']`

and it will redirect to that afterwards.

See [question I asked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269810/custom-submit-handler-stops-working-when-checking-route).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to redirect to the same page, where the comment was submitted.

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id == 'comment_simple_form') {
      $form['#action'] .= '?destination=' . Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
   }
}
```